# Ошибка при выборе MSVC компилятора в Qt Creator

Tags: qt, qtcreator, компилятор

Уже третий день бодаюсь с Qt Creator. Мне нужно создать проект с компилятором MSVC. Qt Creator успешно обнаружил его, но создать проект с ним не дает. Неактивная галка выбора и вот такая ошибка. Что она может значить? Нагуглил один-единственный такой же вопрос, но это было в версии Creator < 5 и вопрос там решился переустановкой. Мне переустановка не помогла

[image: Картинка]

Comment: дык надо в управление комплектами лезть и смотреть чего QtCreator не может найти

Comment: @SergeyTatarincev буду крайне признателен, если скажите, как и где диагностировать проблему. Во вкладке с компиляторами вроде все ок